# Extends JAVA class which is in other class

Tags: java, class, extends

***IDsmCore.java (interface class)***

```
public interface IDsmCore
{
    public void Initialize( String path, String fileName );
    public void Uninitialize( );
}
```

***IDsmToken.java (interface class)***

```
public interface IDsmToken
{
    public String GetID( );
    public void SetID( String id );
}
```

***DsmCore.java (interface implementation)***

```
public class DsmCore implements IDsmCore
{
    @Override
    public void Initialize( String path, String fileName ) {
        // Some code goes here.
    }

    @Override
    public void Uninitialize( ) {
        // Some code goes here.
    }

    public class DsmToken implements IDsmToken
    {
        @Override
        public String GetID( ) {
            // Some code goes here.
        }

        @Override
        public void SetID( String id ) {
            // Some code goes here.
        }
    }
}
```

How you can see `DsmToken` class is in the `DsmCore` class. Now I want to `extends` `DsmToken` class, for example I can extends DsmCore  in this way:

```
public class MyExtendedDsmCore extends DsmCore
{


}
```

***And how I can extends `DsmToken` ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyExtendedDsmCore extends DsmCore.DsmToken {
}
```

and DsmToken should be static.

Comment: Because you can't extend a non-static inner class. It has to be attached to an instance if it's non static.

Comment: @Matthew: But the answer says that!

Answer (score 3):

If the inner class is not qualified as `static` you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Make it static class. But, if you are going to extend the class in two different classes I'd suggest to put it in its own file.

Answer (score -3):

`public class MyExtendedDsmCore extends DsmCore impliments IDsmCore` since it is an interface.

Comment: DsmCore is the class. IDsmCore is the interface